# Plotting a torch.Tensor into an image

Tags: python, pytorch

```
same_digit_imgs = torch.empty(0, 1, 28, 28)
for digit in range(10):
  similar_img = create_interpolates(similar_pairs[digit][0], similar_pairs[digit][1], encoder, decoder)
  print(type(similar_img), similar_img.shape)
  similar_img = similar_img.view(similar_img.shape[1], similar_img.shape[2], similar_img.shape[0])
  plt.imshow(similar_img)
  plt.show()
```

I am trying to plot the `similar_img` Tensor in pytorch.
I am new to pytorch and I am not sure how to plot the image.
The type and the shape is `<class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([9, 1, 28, 28])`

and I am getting an Error:
`RuntimeError: shape '[1, 28, 9]' is invalid for input of size 7056` when I did `similar_img.view(similar_img.shape[1], similar_img.shape[2], similar_img.shape[0])`.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code snippet:

```
for digit in range(10):
    similar_img = create_interpolates(similar_pairs[digit][0], similar_pairs[digit] 
    [1], encoder, decoder)
    print(type(similar_img), similar_img.shape)
    plt.imshow(similar_img[digit].numpy().squeeze())
    plt.show()
```

Thank you